# Backspace key is not working on geeksforgeeks IDE

Tags: linux

I'm doing coding practice on geeksforgeeks IDE, but my backspace key not working.
ctrl+backspace work well but it deletes the whole word. here I want to delete a single character.
I'm Using LINUX 20.04